# How to delete folders that aren't empty?

Tags: powershell-4.0

I am using these lines.  Is there any way to shorten it or is this the best?
Objective is to delete the `Refresh` folder and all of its contents. The script works, but I'd like it to be as minimal as possible.

```bsh
# Set var $Path to equal Refresh folder
$Path = "C:\data\Refresh"
# Find sub-folders of Refresh
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
# Delete Refresh top level folder itself
Remove-Item $Path -Force
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to delete the folder and all its content don't bother with `Get-ChildItem`. Simply call `Remove-Item` with the path you want to delete.

```bsh
$Path = 'C:\data\Refresh'
Remove-Item $Path -Recurse -Force
```

or just

```bsh
Remove-Item 'C:\data\Refresh' -Recurse -Force
```